# When importing an Android project the console says Unable to resolve target 'android-8'

Tags: android, eclipse

When I import an Android project example, then I will see an error like `Unable to resolve target 'android-8` from the Console. This mostly happens when I import projects from other teammembers.

What are the steps needed to resolve this issue?

Comment: This post is off topic because it is not a question.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to fix this:

1. Change the target of the project to something like android-19 or whatever API level you have installed. (Project -> Android -> ..)
2. Install the old android-8 API with the SDK manager.

Answer (score 0):

It's just that the SDK version used for the project was 8 and you don't have it installed. If you have a higher version, there is no problem, it will just use that one.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with android-19.

What I did:

1. Open project.properties file
2. Replace android-19 with android-18
3. Save the file
4. Replace it back with android-19
5. Save again

That worked for me, I think it should be some bug. I hope it works for you too

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this problem:

1. Open Android SDK Manager -> Tools -> Options... -> Clear Cache -> Close Android SDK Manager
2. In Eclipse, Project -> Clean... to refresh current project